# Python code: Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following program in python 2.7 to launch a web page and do an activity. I have parsed the HTML DOM of a web page and was able to make this work when launched via PyCharm IDE or via an Exe created with PyInstaller or via a bat file that wraps an Exe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys


def main():

    try:

        mgmt_console_server_name = sys.argv[1]
        user_session_to_terminate = sys.argv[2]

        # Phase 1: Launch a browser and open the management console page
        # Using IE to access web
        driver = webdriver.Ie('IEDriverServer32.exe')
        return_code = 0

        # Open the management console page.
        driver.get("http://" + mgmt_console_server_name + ":8183/mgmt/security/login.html")

        # Phase 2: Enter the LDAP credentials and hit enter
        # Select the username and the password text boxes
        username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gwt-TextBox')
        password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gwt-PasswordTextBox')

        # Send username information
        username.send_keys('sa-tcnxbot-gds')

        # Send password information
        password.send_keys('zzzzzzzzz')

        # Login to Teamcenter management console with the above set credentials.
        signinbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('GFHWBTICII')
        signinbutton.click()

        # Phase 3: Click on the 'TcServer' component to reach the UI where we can find and kill the user sessions.
        # We are now in the main page. We need to wait till we find an XML element by the ID
        # 'Console'. This signifies that the page has loaded. And we wait at the maximum of 20 seconds.
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Console")))

        # We find the XML element whose InnerHTML is 'Tc Server'.
        tcserverelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Tc Server']")

        # We then find its immediate parent, which is the clickable element and finally click it.
        tcserverclickableelement = tcserverelement.find_element_by_xpath('..')
        tcserverclickableelement.click()

        # Phase 4: We enter the user id whose session is to be terminated in the search field and hit the search.
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Assigned User:']")))

        # We are at the HTML element that has the text 'Assigned User:'
        assigneduserelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Assigned User:']")
        # print(assigneduserelement)
        # An immediate parent of this HTML element is the TD element.
        assigneduserelementparent = assigneduserelement.find_element_by_xpath('..')
        # print(assigneduserelementparent)

        # An immediate sibling of this TD HTML element is another TD element which contains INPUT HTML element.
        assigneduserelementparent.find_element_by_xpath("//TD/following-sibling::TD")
        # print(assigneduserelementparent_sibling)

        # assignedusertextbox = assigneduserelementparent_sibling.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
        # print(assignedusertextbox[0])

        # Send username information
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gwt-TextBox')[1].send_keys(user_session_to_terminate)

        search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Search']")
        # We then find its immediate parent, which is the Search button and finally click it.
        search_button.click()
        time.sleep(4)

        # There would be three cases here.
        # Case 1: The input user has no sessions on his name.
        # Case 2: The input user has one session on his name.
        # Case 3: The input user has more than one sessions on his name.

        # Case 1: This should be one of the table header elements containing the list of servers assigned to the user.
        assigned_server_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[text()='Assigned']")

        if len(assigned_server_rows) == 0:
            return_code = 4
        else:
            # Case 2 and Case 3:
            for each_assigned_server in assigned_server_rows:
                print each_assigned_server.tag_name

                assigned_server_parent_td = each_assigned_server.find_element_by_xpath('..')  # td
                print assigned_server_parent_td.tag_name
                assigned_server_parent_td.click()

                # assigned_server_parent_tr = assigned_server_parent_td.find_element_by_xpath('..')  #tr
                # print assigned_server_parent_tr.tag_name

                # assigned_server_parent_tr.click()

                shutdown_button_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Shutdown Server']")
                shutdown_button_element.click()

                time.sleep(2)
                main_page = driver.window_handles[0]
                alert_window = driver.switch_to.alert
                alert_window.accept()
                driver.switch_to.window(main_page)
    except:
        return_code = 1
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    if return_code == 0:
        print('=> Successfully terminated sessions for the user ' + user_session_to_terminate)
    elif return_code == 4:
        print('=> There are no sessions assigned to the user ' + user_session_to_terminate)
    else:
        print('=> An error occurred while tying to terminate sessions for the user ' + user_session_to_terminate)

    return return_code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But as part of Azure Chatbot, when we tried to plug it in NodeJS code, we are seeing this problem. Is this really some problem with my code?. How should I correctly correct it.

I read on scoping of python but in this case everything is inside the main function and got to know that python try-catches do not add new block scope. So my expectation is that everything should have worked. Please let me know what I am missing.

```
PyAutomationScript Error:Error: Command failed: C:\tcnxbot_data\automated_script\auto.exe localhost pdittaka
[9904] Failed to execute script auto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto.py", line 131, in <module>
  File "auto.py", line 118, in main
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment
```

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Your `finally:` clause is referencing `driver`, whether or not the body of the `try` succeeding in assigning a value to that variable.

Comment: Yes @jasonharper, I also tried moving the driver variable initialization inside of main and before the try block. Still in vain.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the line inside the finally function. What you are essentially saying is irrespective of whether there is an error or not (whether it goes into try or except) execute `driver.quit()`.

But if your code runs into and error inside the try before or during the driver is defined, it goes into the except, then the finally where you are attempting to close the driver. However, this is not possible because the driver hasn't been defined yet. What you can do is add this at the beginning of the main function:

`driver = None`

and change the code inside the `finally:` to be this:

```
if driver is not None:
   driver.quit()
```